# UICollectionView CoreData. Missplaced cells after update

Tags: ios, core-data, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView with one section showing a grid of images.
The problem is when i do updates and the result count is smaller then the initial item count.
The cells are placed randomly in "old" empty spots but i want the collectionView to place them one after the other starting from top left.

Im using this code when doing updates:

```
// Fetch request above this code
[_collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    [_collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];
} completion:nil];
[_collectionView reloadData];
```

I have no custom flowLayout. I'm using this:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
```

Should i delete cells in the animation block?

Is there a way to force collectionView to reload completely?

Edit:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView   cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FTRecipeIndexCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (!cell) {
    cell = [[FTRecipeIndexCell alloc] init];
}
Recipe *recipe = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:recipe.thumbnail];
float size = _collectionView.bounds.size.width / 6;
[cell setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size, size)];
   return cell;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count];
}
```

Got it to work.
I was setting the cellFrame incorrectly resulting in wild west positioning of cells.
Since i only use a imageView on the cell i replaced my custom cell with this code.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Recipe *recipe = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:recipe.thumbnail]];

    float size = _collectionView.bounds.size.width / 6;

   [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size, size)];
   [cell addSubview:imageView];
 return cell;
}
```

Comment: Deletion of the cells would be quite inefficient. THe method: dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath does the job very efficiently and it would be unwise delete the cells.

Although I would like to see more code I suspect the problem lies in 

    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath       Can you show us the code for it?

Comment: Please, EDIT your original questions and add the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the code:

```
    if (!cell) {
    cell = [[FTRecipeIndexCell alloc] init];
}
```

Delete this code block. It is not needed, it can only cause the problems if

```
FTRecipeIndexCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

for some reason wouldn't return the cell.

If you change the content count in any section, then UICollectionView has to get the change through Delegate method:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

meaning, if you don't supply the record count per section dynamically here, then UICollectionView will assume the old count is still valid and will dequeue the cells with old content you don't want any more.

If you implement this correctly, then you should have no problems with it, since you have most probably image view as subview to the cell and you have it connected as property outlet.
Adding content to UICollectionViewCell programmatically, however, does require some additional tricks if you want it to work properly and efficient.

EDIT:

```
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView   dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Recipe *recipe = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:recipe.thumbnail]];

    float size = _collectionView.bounds.size.width / 6;

   [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size, size)];
   [cell addSubview:imageView];
 return cell;
}
```

THe code above is also not good enough:

Never add content to view, but to contentView of the cell
You need to manage content more clever, when you add the cell programatically, but at the end it is more clear, since you don't spread the logic between code and NIB. I suggest you do it as following:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
Recipe *recipe = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:recipe.thumbnail]];
float size = _collectionView.bounds.size.width / 6;

[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size, size)];

// remove subviews, otherwise the content will overlap
for (UIView *current in [cell.contentView subviews]) {[current removeFromSuperview];}
// always add to contentView property
[cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
return cell;
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your replies!

The delegate method reports correct number of items in section but cells are still placed randomly.

Maybe the problem lies in that I make everything programmatically including my cell views. As you pointed out it may need some more work.
Can you point me in the right direction?